# Argument of type '(a: number, b: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: (string | number)[]) => string'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Below is a makeSafe function, that is being called in the test below.

```
import { expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { Equal, Expect } from '../helpers/type-utils';

const makeSafe =
  <Args extends string | number, R>(func: (...args: Args[]) => R) =>
  (
    ...args: Args[]
  ):
    | {
        type: 'success';
        result: R;
      }
    | {
        type: 'failure';
        error: Error;
      } => {
    try {
      const result = func(...args);

      return {
        type: 'success',
        result,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        type: 'failure',
        error: e as Error,
      };
    }
  };

it("Should properly match the function's arguments", () => {
  const func = makeSafe((a: number, b: string) => {
    return `${a} ${b}`;
  });

  // @ts-expect-error
  func();

  // @ts-expect-error
  func(1, 1);

  func(1, '1');
});
```

typescript infer args as (string | number)[] for the above code, and hence I'm getting this error

[ts-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCXA.png)

```
Argument of type '(a: number, b: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: (string | number)[]) => string'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2345)
```

But with the below type definition of makeSafe function, typescript infer args as the literal tuple [a: number, b: string] and so I don't get any error and the test passes

```
import { expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { Equal, Expect } from '../helpers/type-utils';

const makeSafe =
  <Args extends (string | number)[], R>(func: (...args: Args) => R) =>
  (
    ...args: Args
  ):
    | {
        type: 'success';
        result: R;
      }
    | {
        type: 'failure';
        error: Error;
      } => {
    try {
      const result = func(...args);

      return {
        type: 'success',
        result,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        type: 'failure',
        error: e as Error,
      };
    }
  };
```

The only difference in both solutions is how the typescript infers the argument args, why does typescript is doing so?

Answer (score 0):

It actually works as expected when you define `Args extends string | number` and use it as `...args: Args[]`. In case when you pass `(a: number, b: string)` `Args` evaluates to `string | number` and you get `string | number[]`. So basically your generic evaluates one of the elements of the array, not the whole array. However, in your second case, you expect an array of elements that `extends string | number` and this lets the compiler fully understand the type of the `...args`